# Ionic + Angular+ Mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, ionic-framework, mongoose, one-to-many

I just want to display the zipCode and town from _id address in database.By now i have just the id display but i want to show zipCode ( 1140) and town( Evere).
Thanks a lot

Address class
[addressClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uojLU.png)
Session class with relationships
[sessionClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYIVF.png)
DisplayHTML
[Htmlcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Tt2.png)
Result now
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwshv.png)

Comment: Please add more details and also remove the image with actual code because no would like to write all the code for an answer.  Provide more debugging details otherwise it'll be voted to close

Comment: it a relationship between Session and Address .  I added session with an address when i want to display the address i have only the _id of address but i would like to see the zipcode and the town

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.